# Tooltip on mouse click. Code snippet works but when embedded on a website, it does not work. Not sure why

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, mouseclick-event, onmouseclick

I have a full-screen click area. A tooltip appears near the mouse pointer on mouse click and disappears on mouse move. The code snippet seems to work fine. But when I embed the code on my website, it throws an error: `$ is not a function. (In '$(document)', '$' is undefined).` Not sure why. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
          
              $('.fullscreen-click-area').click(showBox).mousemove(hideBox);
          
              function showBox(e){
                  $('.tooltip').fadeIn().css(({ left:  e.pageX, top: e.pageY }));
              }
              
              function hideBox(){
                  $('.tooltip').fadeOut();
              }
          });
```

```css
      .fullscreen-click-area {
          background-color: #7F7F7F;
          position: absolute;
          top: 50%;
          left: 50%;
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          width: 100%;
          height: 100vh;
        }
        
        .tooltip {
            margin:10px;
            padding:12px;
            border:2px solid #000;
            width:60px;
            position: absolute;
            display: none;
            background-color: #fff;
            
        }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>

<div class="fullscreen-click-area"></div>
<div class="tooltip">TOOLTIP</div>
```

Comment: @j08691 I assume that the first line of HTML code is jQuery library inclusion, no?

Comment: @j08691 I've included the first line of HTML code on my website as well. Still not working.

Comment: Well, we need a [mcve] here. So you'll need to whittle the code down on your site until you arrive at a [mcve] that will reproduce the issue here, where it's currently working

Comment: Also, is your site running WordPress? If so, try changing the `$` to `jQuery`, e.g. `jQuery(document).ready`

Comment: So you tried the `$` to `jQuery` change and it doesn't work? You're also not getting any other errors about jQuery not being loaded?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about testing with blank pages

Comment: Why would I need to delete my comments?

Comment: All four would be the fastest test. If that works there are ways around having to do it at all

Comment: @j08691 That did the trick. Thank you! Could I ask you another question? I see that the jQuery library is 125 KB. Is it really necessary to load the entire library just for a tooltip? Or is there a way to embed just the absolutely necessary code snippet from the jQuery library? Thanks.

Comment: Google jQuery slim for a more lightweight version.